# Building TAR file with USTAR header in Coldfusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, tar

I am building a TAR archive in ColdFusion. Someone was nice enough to help me figure out how to do that with JAVA, but the system I'm submitting the TAR file to says it is getting an error because the header is not in USTAR format. I'm getting nowhere trying to figure out how to change the header format. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code I'm using with CF10 on Windows Server 2012:

```
 <!--- put the files into a TAR file --->
         <cfscript>
            // Initialize TAR file to generate
            outputPath = "#thisbatchDir##thisBatchNumber#.tar";
            os = createObject("java", "java.io.FileOutputStream").init(outputPath);
            tar = createObject("java", "org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveOutputStream").init(os);
            dir = "#thisBatchNumber#/";

            // tar.ustarFormat('true');


            // Create an entry from a file (lst file)
            inputFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("#thisbatchDir##thisLstFilename#");
            entry = tar.createArchiveEntry(inputFile, "#dir##thisLstFilename#");
            tar.putArchiveEntry(entry);
            tar.write(FileReadBinary(inputFile));
            tar.closeArchiveEntry();

            sleep(1000);

            for (image in qryGetBatchImagesData) {

            // Create an entry from a file (tif files)
            inputFile = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("#thisbatchDir##image.vImageFileName#");
            entry = tar.createArchiveEntry(inputFile, "#dir##thisBatchNumber##numberFormat(image.iPageNum - 1,'000')#bf.tif");
            tar.putArchiveEntry(entry);
            tar.write(FileReadBinary(inputFile));
            tar.closeArchiveEntry();

            sleep(1000);

            }

            // create a second entry in a folder (trnsact file)
            inputFile2 = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("#thisbatchDir#transact.dat");
            entry2 = tar.createArchiveEntry(inputFile2, "#dir#transact.dat");
            tar.putArchiveEntry(entry2);
            tar.write(FileReadBinary(inputFile2));
            tar.closeArchiveEntry();

            sleep(1000);

            // create a second entry in a folder (eob file)
            eobFileInput = createObject("java", "java.io.File").init("#thisbatchDir##thisBatchNumber#.eob");
            entry2 = tar.createArchiveEntry(eobFileInput, "#thisBatchNumber#.eob");
            tar.putArchiveEntry(entry2);
            tar.write(FileReadBinary(eobFileInput));
            tar.closeArchiveEntry();

            // Close TAR file
            tar.flush();
            tar.close();
        </cfscript>
```

Comment: I opened the file in a hex editor and I see this:
.ustar.00NYC-DBD
EV01$...........

Comment: Just FYI, the system I'm submitting this file to is FileNET, if that makes any difference.

Comment: I am not familiar with FileNet, but it what is the exact error message? Also, silly question but ... did you do a search on the error message? .tar is a pretty common format, so it seems likely someone else has encountered the issue before.